# why I can not use inline alert() in pug template if calling it from "if condition"?

Tags: javascript, iteration, pug, inline

I read in an [article](https://www.filosophy.org/post/34/using_javascript_functions_within_the_jade_templating_language/) that I can use inline functions by defining them using - var = function(...){...}, but when I code:

```
    - var tryit = function tryit(tasks) {alert('will not work')};
    if tasks
          #adiv #{tryit(tasks)}
```

I get this error message:

```
if supervisor tryit is not a function
```

I scanned all pug documentation (well there is no such thing there, sure!), please tell me how I can have this approach, so that I could further process my variable 'tasks' sent from server in client side.

My use case is that if I have a json array from server, process it further and add a tree structure of DOM elements. Then finally append it to the div(id='adiv'). I can't anyway figure out how to do this, because when I use document.createElement(...) I get a similar error like the above with alert(..). I tried by script. but then I can't call the method I declared in script. in pug template with #{myScriptedFunc(...)}.

**Edit:**

What surprises me more: if I change it to:

```
- var tryit = function() {console.log('silence!');};
    if tasks
          #adiv #{tryit()}
```

There will be no error message, but the output will be in server side (in command line window where I run the server), not in the browser, meaning that the line was executed in server side? But I expected to have it run in client side. The way to do such a post-processing in client side is still a mistry to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable should hold the 'name' of the function, the function itself should be anonymous.

```
var tryit = function (tasks) {
  alert('will work')
};
```

so `var tryit = function tryit(tasks)` becomes `var tryit = function(tasks)`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typos, I just corrected it, the same way it fails: "if supervisor alert is not a function". I've been stucked now an hour, any solution please?

Comment: the part I changed was to get rid of the name after function, I'll ad an edit

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it didn't work again, I finally understood that all of that happens in server side, so alert() obviously can not work there at all.

Answer (score 1):

Alert can work, it doesnt look wonderful, but here it is:

`if messages !== null
    each message in messages
       mixin alertMessage(message)
          script.
               debugger;
               alert(message);
       +alertMessage(message)
else 
    mixin alertMessage()
        script.
             debugger;
             alert('Hey Look i work!');
    +alertMessage()`

Utlizing a **mixin** will allow you to call a function like block of code that you can put plain javascript in.

I suppose you could do the if check and just put the

> **script.**

tag after that, but the

> **mixin**

will allow you to iterate through an array or object you send in the route with

> **res.render('myPage', { anonymous object });**